# Is it possible to store a file in SVN which cannot be seen by other users

Tags: svn

I have a file which is kind of confidential which should not be seen by users other than my own . Is it possible?

Comment: I think your only option is to just not check it in to SVN. Google the `svn:ignore` property.

Comment: @MatrixFrog:  Using path based Authorization, this can be done.  Look below.

Comment: You're totally right. Nevermind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Subversion does [Path Based Authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html), so yes. The linked documentation has an example with a "secret" directory. You can also use `* =` to take away all access by default, and then grant it again for a specific group like this:

```
[/path/to/secret]
* =
@secret_users = rw

[groups]
secret_users=alice,bob
```

When somebody without authorization tries to read the file, they will get a `403 Forbidden` (if the repository is hosted with apache - I assume another similar error is shown if you use `svnserve`).

Comment: NOTE: This only works on directories, not files.  Those who have permission can see the directory, but not the file(s) or other directories contained in that directory.

Comment: NOTE 2 - This only works for svn-http-https-ssh connections. If your repo hosted on disk with direct file:// protocol, all authorization restrictions will be ignored